# поиск набора символов отвечающего определенным параметрам в тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x

задача такая : есть некоторый текст состоящий из символов аcgt , нужно найти в нем все варианты из 10 символов , в каждом наборе a+t==g+c , длинна набора 10 символов, последние буквы g или c , не случайные наборы , а идущие по списку, как бы сканируя список некоторой "рамкой",если подходит , сохраняем, если нет то сдвигаем ее на 1 вправо , при чем искать надо не приближаясь  на 60 символов вправо и лево к отмеченной знаками @ области (за пределами области)

```
a1=input().lower()
a,k1,k2 ,last_list1,last_list2,simv=[],[],[],[],[],['a','g','c','t','@'] #куча списков потому что я не придумал ничего лучше
for i in a1:# цикл просеивает все лишнее , пробелы , цифры и тд
    if i in simv:
        a.append(i)
ind1=a.index('@') #находим индекс разделителя, нужен для определения области поиска 
a[ind1]='!'
ind2=a.index('@')
a[ind2]='!'
list1,list2=a[0:ind1-60],a[ind2+61:len(a)+1] #разрезаем список на 2. каждый содержит только допустимую для поиска облась
for i in list1:   #  циклом наполняю список к1 до длинны в 10
    if len(k1)<10: 
        k1.append(i)
    if len(k1)==10 and (k1.count('a')+k1.count('t')==k1.count('g')+k1.count('c')) and k1[9]=='c' or k1[9]=='g' :
        last_list1.append(k1) # фильтрую по условию(длинна,соотношение букв, окончание)
    if len(k1)==10: # удаляю первый символ , что бы цикл вернувшись в начало присоединил в конец еще 1 и "сдвинул " вправо
        del k1[0]
for i in list2:
    if len(k2)<10:
        k2.append(i)
    if len(k2)==10 and (k2.count('a')+k2.count('t')==k2.count('g')+k2.count('c')) and k2[9]=='c' or k2[9]=='g' :
        last_list2.append(k2)
    if len(k2)==10:
        del k2[0]
print(last_list1,last_list2)
```

в конце должно получится 2 списка , но питонтьютор говорит IndexError: list index out of range в  строке где проверяется условие, а intellij говорит ValueError: '@' is not in list и ее не смущает что этот символ в тексте на 5 строк выше
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
я сдаюсь , спасибо если кто поможет

Comment: Можете привести пример исходных данных?

Comment: 1 ttaatagact gtgcagaatt ttaacgtttt ataattttga acctgttatt ctggactaaa
       61 tcttcttgaa ggagaaacat gtcagagaat cacatatctg tgctaatatt ttaatataat
      121 gcttaaaata gtttcattgt tatagatgag cagtaaagtt cccaaggagg aaaaggaaga
      181 tgttcactta ctctctttcc ctttg gcagattcac atatg ctgagtttac cacatcttag
      241 gagcagacag cttctttatg atgagttgga tgaagtaaac ccacgtctt@c@ gagaacccca
      301 agagctcttt tccattttgt ctaccaagag gccactgcag gctccaagat ggccaattga
      361 atgtgaggtc atcaaggaaa acatccatca tattggtaat atgacttact cacagtggtc
      421 ttgctattct gcctgacttt tttttttttt tttt

Comment: Скобочки вокруг `k1[9]=='c' or k1[9]=='g'` забыли. Вот на `k1[9]=='g'`и вылазит `Out of Range`.

Comment: "причем искать надо на 60 символов вправо и влево от отмеченной знаками @ области" и `list1,list2=a[0:ind1-60],a[ind2+61:len(a)+1]` - так ищем внутри области +/-60 (я так понял из текста задания) или таки за пределами этой области (выходит по вашему коду)?

Comment: за пределами области, +- 60 это "запретная" область

Comment: перестало ругаться, спсибо за скобки , но проблема в intellij осталась ,она упорно не видит знак @ , а в пайтон тьюторе не смотря на то , что он не ругается, списки конечные все равно пустые

Comment: А не подаёте ли ли вы многострочные данные на вход? `input()` читает только первую строку и там вообще ещё нет символов `@`. Распечатайте вашу `a1` да посмотрите, что на самом деле на входе.

Comment: да, правда только 1 строку видит, я даже и не знал этого , а как тогда ввод делать? только в код вставлять эту стену текста?

Comment: Либо одной очень длинной строкой вводить. Либо в цикле делать `input()` и конкатенировать введённые строки до тех пор как на вход не придёт, скажем, пустая строка.

Comment: огромное спасибо, все получилось, все работает как надо,с вводом решил не усложнять , проще в ворде в 1 строку все переделать

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как-то так:

```
valid_symbols = "agct@"

data = input()
data = "".join([v for v in data.lower() if v in valid_symbols])    # просеиваем всё лишнее, пробелы, цифры и тд
data1, _, data2 = data.split('@')  # берём части левее и правее блока @...@

found = []
for src in [data1[:-60], data2[60:]]:  # итерируемся по обеим частям, обрезанным как нам требуется
    found.append([])
    for pos in range(len(src)-10):  
        text = src[pos:pos+10]  # идём по входным данным "рамкой" длиной 10
        if text[-1] in "cg" and text.count('a')+text.count('t') == text.count('g')+text.count('c'): # проверяем наше условие
            found[-1].append(text)

print(found)
```

Comment: спасибо, там должно 2 списка получится, но смысл я понял , по пробую сейчас сделать 2 отдельно 
ошибка data1, _, data2 = data.split('@')  # берём части левее и правее блока @...@
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) при чем ее нет  в пайтон тьюторе, но есть в IDLE и intellij

Comment: Я уже предположил, что на вход вы даёте многострочные данные и `@` у вас не в первой строке. Или что-то в ваших IDE. На чистом питоне работает же.

Comment: @TommyValachi Поправил чтобы в результате было 2 списка.